# Android Smack gives bad IQ Result

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm writing an app that I'm using the Smack library for.  My issue is that I can see that the Stanza I send is getting the correct result stanza back but no matter what listener I try I only get a result stanza back with a fraction of the data not even in order.

The weird thing is that the debugger is getting back what I need and should be getting.  I just can't seem to recreate that response in code.  What should I do so I can see and use the same data the SMACK debugger is getting?

```
            mConnection.sendIqWithResponseCallback(iq, new StanzaListener() {
            @Override
            public void processStanza(Stanza packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException {
                Log.e("Packet ", packet.toXML().toString());
            }
        });
```